# Best layout properties CSS (e.g. for a menu bar)

Tags: html, css, layout, properties, responsive-design

I want to make a menu bar and I have always seen that front-end developers tend to use either float: left property or display: inline-block property or even both or something similar.

Since I have been into the flexbox property and grid property and knowing that float is not a property meant for layout, I wonder what is best practice of making a horizontal menu.

Using an unordered list with list items aswell, is this actually a 'proper' way of making such menu (considering semantic HTML)?

What properties/tags should a 'perfect' menu consist out of (aiming towards responsive design aswell)?

(Also I am aiming towards an answer that explains what is best-practice as for the time we live in now, since CSS has been in development and things might have changed in due time.)

Comment: I think use of `unordered list` is proper way for making menu also for `resplnsive ` design u should use `media queries`

Comment: I agree media queries is a good option, I have seen multiple examples making use of such and creating a toggle button for a menu.

Answer (score 1):

I use it without problem. Float has been adapted to be used in many situations that it was never meant to. If I want a right sided nav bar. I float my ul right, float my li left, and display: inline. Works like a charm, and seems to be standard practice from what I have seen. I just spit that out off the top of my head, but pretty sure that's what i do, in general. You can then just use the media query to change display: block and put the li widths to 100%, if you wanted a vertical navbar on mobile phones, and a horizontal on desktop. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It just gives me a weird feeling using something for something it is not intended. I would love to work with tools I am certain that it is used as intended, though I agree some things are just the way they are and if you can make things possible that way, then so be it, since developers use everything at their disposal in first place. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: No problem, glad I could give some incite!

Answer (score 1):

I always use codepen/patterns to discover great layouts! Check it out.

Comment: This should be comment rather then answer.